# fb.ui share_open_graph vs share

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

A week ago the picture argument was killed by facebook and since than I am trying to bring back the old behavior in my website.

With

```
                FB.ui({
                method: 'share_open_graph',
                action_type: 'og.shares',
                action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                    object: { 
                        'og:url': data.href,
                        'og:title': data.title,
                        'og:description': data.description,
                        'og:image': data.picture
                    }
                })
            },
```

I can have an image but this does not allow users to share the link on facebook pages they manage, only on their wall.

With `FB.ui({
                    app_id: FacebookAppId,
                    method: 'share',
                    href: data.href,
                    picture: data.picture,
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description,
                    caption: 'WriteCraft' 
                },`

The link is shared but since "picture" is deprecated there is no image at all.

Is there a solution to the issue?

Comment: the solution is to include the correct og tags in the shared url

Comment: What og tags would allow for users to share the post on pages they manage, and not only on their wall?

Comment: well, the usual ones? http://ogp.me/ - it does not depend on the og tags. you can also use sharer.php, for example.

Comment: Well this is not really related to the issue.

The issue is that with 'share' you can't use og tags and therefore you can't have an image but with 'share_open_graph' users can't share the post on pages they manage. 
If the og tags have some sort of effect on that it would be really surprising. And if you know how they do what am I missing in the example above?

Comment: of course you can use og tags with share. just use og:image in the url and it will be there when you share the url

Comment: But the share method is not allowing for action properties?

Where should I put the tags in that case

`FB.ui({
                    app_id: FacebookAppId,
                    method: 'share',
                    href: data.href,
                    picture: data.picture,
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description,
                    caption: 'WriteCraft' 
                },`

Comment: in the url, as metatags. NOT in the api call.

Comment: @Lobotomy, Have you found any answer? I am also going through the same issue, is there any way to share post on timeline with open graph?

Answer (score 0):

To post image on fb , change method to feed from share. it may works.

```
FB.ui({
                method: 'feed', 
                display: 'popup',
                picture: data.picture,
               }),
```